# MongoDB GridFS VS Directly disk IO

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

Use MongoDB GridFS store images and images stored directly on disk What are the advantages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Main advantage in my opinion is easy files distribution across multiple servers when system start growing (sharding, replication).
2. Easy improvement reads/writes speed.
3. No need to care where to put new file.
4. Files systems become slow with big amount of small files.

Comment: Are the advantages applicable to normal BSON documents too?. I want to store images which are less than 16Mb in database? Thanks in advance